# Showing closure is $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{p_n\}$ be the set of all primes. Define $E_n = \{ r+ \sqrt{p_n} \mid r \in \mathbb{Q}\}$. Show that $E_n$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. That is, the closure of $E_n$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

So, does this mean I have to show the closure of $E_n$ is $(-\infty, \infty)$? I'm not sure how to do that. Ideas?

Comment: HINT: Given $x \in \mathbb{R}$ There are values in $\mathbb{Q}$ near $x - \sqrt{p_n}$

Comment: $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, so you could just extend that proof. I'm not sure what the end-goal of this theorem is.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Unrelated to the question, but why is it that $E_n \cap E_m = \emptyset$ if $m \neq n$? This is stated in the notes of our lecture, but no reason is specified.

Comment: @Tlani All the $\sqrt{p_n}$ are irrational and different

Answer (score 1):

*Hint* You can check that $\Bbb Q$ is dense and the transition of dense set on the set of reals are dense.